# AttributeError: module 'sklearn.cluster' has no attribute 'k_means_'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a weird error:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

from nose.tools import assert_equal, assert_is_instance, assert_true, assert_is_not
from numpy.testing import assert_array_equal, assert_array_almost_equal, assert_almost_equal
```

My data is stored as an array like this, just bigger:

```
array([[-2.65602062e+00, -1.38241098e+00, -6.04632297e-01,
     9.37261785e-01, -8.33086491e-01, -1.61945768e-01,
     1.54809554e-01, -2.62093027e-02, -2.78241107e-01,
    -2.42455888e-01]]
```

I define a function

```
def cluster(array, random_state, n_clusters=10):

    model = KMeans(n_clusters = n_clusters, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 0).fit(array)
    clusters = model.fit_predict(array)

    return model, clusters
```

But this gives me an error when I do a unit test:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-d502eebc4ee1> in <module>
  1 k_means_t, cluster_t = cluster(reduced, 
random_state=check_random_state(1), n_clusters=5)
  2 
----> 3 assert_is_instance(k_means_t, sklearn.cluster.k_means_.KMeans)
      4 assert_is_instance(cluster_t, np.ndarray)
      5 assert_equal(k_means_t.n_init, 10)


AttributeError: module 'sklearn.cluster' has no attribute 'k_means_'
```

My code worked before, not sure what happened since.

I removed `kmeans_` from `assert_is_instance(k_means_t, sklearn.cluster.k_means_.KMeans)` and the error disappeared, but I do not think it is a correct solution.

Comment: Isn't the class ```sklearn.cluster._kmeans.KMeans```?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.k_means.html

Comment: But in the test it is given as `assert_is_instance(k_means_t, sklearn.cluster.k_means_.KMeans)`

Comment: The function returns the model as the first item in the tuple, I looked at ```type(model)``` and at least on my system it is ```sklearn.cluster._kmeans.KMeans```